# GraphQL - Query Seems Fine but Getting 400 Error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, express-graphql

So, whenever I try to add a product to the inventory list, via a mutation, I get a `POST http://localhost:3000/graphql 400 (Bad Request)`. I can perform the mutation in the sandbox without issue. And, the query to retrieve information works just fine. I have double-checked all the names being used and nothing seems off. Here is the code:

From App.jsx:

```
async createProduct(product) {
    const query = `mutation addProduct($product: ProductInputs!) {
      addProduct(product: $product) {
        id
      }
    }`;

    await fetch('/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables: { product }})
    });

    await this.loadData();
}
```

From schema.graphql:

```
enum InventoryCategory {
  Shirts
  Jeans
  Jackets
  Sweaters
  Accessories
}

type Product {
  id: Int!
  category: InventoryCategory!
  name: String!
  price: Float
  imageURL: String
}

"Toned down Product, used as inputs, without server generated values."
input ProductInputs {
  category: InventoryCategory!
  name: String
  price: Float
  imageURL: String
}

##### Top level declarations

type Query {
  productList: [Product!]!
}

type Mutation {
  addProduct(product: ProductInputs!): Product!
}
```

From server.js

```
const inventoryDB = [];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    productList,
  },
  Mutation: {
    addProduct,
  },
};

function productList() {
  return inventoryDB;
}

function addProduct(_, { product }) {
  product.id = inventoryDB.length + 1;
  inventoryDB.push(product);
  return product;
}
```

Is there anything that stands out as being obviously incorrect? I cannot seem to figure out why I keep getting the 400 error. I cannot seem to find an issue with the query (mutation) itself. Any thoughts?

Edit: The query to retrieve information works just fine. See below for the code:

```
async loadData() {
    const query = `query {
      productList {
        id
        category
        name
        price
        imageURL
      }
    }`;

    const response = await fetch('/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({ query })
    });

    const body = await response.text();
    const result = JSON.parse(body);
    this.setState({ products: result.data.productList });
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? What does `product` look like in your minimal case causing the error? Do you still get the 400 if you try to just query without any mutation?

Comment: For the error message, are you looking for something more specific than the 400? It just points to the fetch function.

I do not get the 400 if I try to query without any mutation. I will load that query about in a moment.

Comment: You can look at the "Network" tab in your browser's web tools to see what other information (and in what format) the sandbox is sending, and compare that with the network request caused by your coded mutation call.  There might be some additional headers or other stuff that you're not sending in your request.  That the "query" works suggests everything is OK, but it's still worth checking to see what the differences are.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to convert the price from the text input to a float. The app works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out the problem. The issue was with the price, which GraphQL expected to be a float, but I was sending a string. I had to convert the text input to the proper format and voila, it worked. For the conversion I used:

```
parseFloat(form.price.value.substring(1))
```

and also used:

```
{new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}).format(product.price)}
```

to ensure correct display formatting.